# Format a column with percentage using VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am exporting a report to Excel from Access through VBA. There is a column in the report that should be formatted as percentage and round. How can I format this?

Answer (score 1):

Set the *Format* property of the textbox in the report to: Percent

You may have to divide the value by 100 first. If so, rename the textbox to anything else than the name of the field, and use this expression as *ControlSource*:

```
=[YourFieldName]/100
```

For a new formatted string value, use Format:

```
=Format([YourFieldName],"Percent")
```

You don't mention what kind of rounding you need, but functions for all general methods of rounding are listed here: [Rounding values up, down, by 4/5, or to significant figures](https://rdsrc.us/d59ZMe)

Comment: I have already the value. I just need to convert the column to percent style.